# How do I stop a sort at a certain point in the column?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a spreadsheet that automatically sorts itself by the date in column D.

```
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("D:D")) Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("sorting col D")
'    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Range("D1").Sort Key1:=Range("D2"), _
    Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
    OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
    Orientation:=xlTopToBottom

'    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If
```

This code works fine.

What I want to do is limit the sorting to the first N rows.  Unfortunately, N is not a fixed number.  Basically there will be information in column K for SOME of the rows (and all of the rows with column K will be at the bottom of the sheet).  So I only want the sort to be performed for the rows in which there is no data in column K.

[image: img1]

So in this picture, supposing there are dates in column D for all the green rows too, if I added a new row with a date in column D, it would sort it BUT ONLY AMONG ROWS 2-10, leaving rows 11+ alone.  I do not want the green rows resorted by column D, as they are sorted by something else.  Sorry for the vague photo!

Comment: Why not just replace `Range("D1")` by the range that you actually want to sort?

Comment: @JohnColeman thanks for your reply; I don't know how to select that range, since it will change each time I add a row to the sheet; it's not a fixed range but a range that should grow and be limited by the situation in col K.

Comment: Determine the first cell in column `K` with data? `N = Range("K1").End(XlDown).Row() - 1` (or some variation of that) should work.

Comment: Sort first on ColK then on ColD

Comment: @TimWilliams won't this place the cells with blank col k at the bottom?

Comment: @TimWilliams I think since I have colors in the sheet I can sort by color and date

Comment: OK well I guess I should have tried that first - I thought you could fix that with sort order...  Another possibility would be to put some other value in the blank cells.

Comment: add an empty row where you want to stop. that's how you do it, then delete it back.

Comment: Have you thought/looked at Excel dynamic named ranges? See https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/dynamic-named-range.html